# How to add button on a particular cell in tableview.When i tried it displayed in all cell

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitableview

The ttile shows my question.I want to add button on 2 nd and 5 th cell only.And How can i do this?

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5) {
                      // here button creation code
                     }
             }
```

When it runs first time it display in particular cell but after scroll it displayed on all cell in tableview.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: I' didn't down voted your question.

Answer (score 2):

This will work fine:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    // here is the redbutton

    if indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5{
        var redBtn = UIButton()
        redBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
        redBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell.addSubview(redBtn)
    }


    //label text just added from an array

    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

Comment: I tried this already.But when scroll or select ,the button displays on every cell

Comment: yes it worked i think in my other codes make mistake will check thanks

Comment: I got the porblem just make your tableview height to 100 then scroll then you can see the problem

Comment: Check my updated project with custom cell:https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Add-Button-At-perticuler-cell

Answer (score 1):

put condition in cell for row at indexpath :

if `indexPath.row` == somevalue then :

```
    var button=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(150, 240, 75, 30))
    button.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.tag = 1010
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    cell.contentView.addSubview(button)
```

Just remove the button from the cell in else part :

```
cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1010).removeFromSuperview()
```